# Are there Clojure-like STM libraries for C

Tags: c, clojure, stm

Are there any libraries that bring `ref`s, `atom`s and `agent`s to C code?

Are there also structural sharing libraries for C to accompany?

Comment: You can look at one of implementations code.google.com/p/rstm, example of usage code.google.com/p/rstm/wiki/WritingApps. Keep in mind that C is low level programming language so it's not correct to compare it with clojure.

Comment: The following information is not worthy of a full answer, but I pulled this off Google Groups https://github.com/Chouser/clojure-jna

Comment: There is more about this at this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/UWBpyHndluA

Comment: octopusgrabbus, clojure-jna is not about that. It's more about integrating real Clojure with C code. I expecting some lightweight solution that does only STM and structural sharing (maybe with "manual" garbage collection limited to that structures), not the entire big JVM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge no.

Even if there was, IMHO it wouldn't be a particularly good fit for C code:

- These approaches depend heavily on the JVM to provide **memory management and garbage collection**. Structural sharing, in particular, implies that you can't easily determine who else is using a particular block of a data structure. So you really want automatic GC to clear this  up when the last reference to a structural component disappears.
- The usefulness of the STM constructs is really in **concurrent situations**. It's much harder to write good concurrent code in C than in a JVM language where threading support is pervasive and more consistent across platforms / libraries.
- At least in the way that they are used in Clojure, the STM constructs are designed to be used in a **functional programming language** (i.e. a language where functions are pure, where you typically code by composing higher order functions and data is immutable). e.g. the function `swap!` for updating an atom is itself a higher order function.

While I'm not saying that you can't write functional-style STM code in C if you are determined enough.... it's not a good fit though, and you'd probably end up reinventing something like Lisp anyway. I'm reminded of Greenspun's tenth rule of programming:

> Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad hoc,
>   informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of
>   Common Lisp.

Basically, use the right tool for the job :-)